# Writing arrays in a dataframe to csv

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I read a parquet file into a dataframe using pandas. The dataframe looks as follows.

```
  import pandas as pd
 
  dat1 = pd.read_parquet("myParquetFile.parquet")
  dat1

  Name Age Numbers
  John  33  [12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456]
  Zorro 34  [0.98,0.0009,.123]


  dat1.to_csv("myCSVFile.csv", index=False)
```

Now the csv file looks like this:

```
    Name Age Numbers
    John  33  [12.0 0.99989 0.3456]
    Zorro 34  [0.98 0.0009  .123]
```

I need to write these dataframes into a csv file. When I do so, i see that the values in the 'Numbers' column are missing a comma in the csv. How can I ensure that the list values are comma separated as below?

```
    Name Age Numbers
    John  33  [12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456]
    Zorro 34  [0.98,0.0009,.123]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If write data to csv, always converted to strings - numbers, arrays,..., csv file not save types of data.  What is reason for it?

Comment: But if need only add `,` I think converting to list should help - `df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].apply(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all data saved to `csv` is text.

If need only add `,` I think converting from `array`s to `list`s should help:

```
dat1.assign(Numbers = dat1['Numbers'].apply(list)).to_csv('myCSVFile.csv', index=False)
```

For read column like lists use `converters`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myCSVFile.csv', converters={'Numbers': lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)})
print (df)
    Name  Age                  Numbers
0   John   33  [12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456]
1  Zorro   34    [0.98, 0.0009, 0.123]

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Numbers']))
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV format is only text, the dtypes are inferred during import of the data.

If you want to keep the commas, you must convert to string before exporting:

```
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Zorro'],
                     'Age': [33, 34],
                     'Numbers': [[12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456], [0.98, 0.0009, 0.123]]})
dat1.astype({'Numbers': str}).to_csv('myCSVFile.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
Name,Age,Numbers
John,33,"[12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456]"
Zorro,34,"[0.98, 0.0009, 0.123]"
```

Then to read your data, you need to convert back to lists:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('myCSVFile.csv')
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age                  Numbers
0   John   33  [12.0, 0.99989, 0.3456]
1  Zorro   34    [0.98, 0.0009, 0.123]
```